# Sphinxbase make/install failing

Tags: c, debian, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to install sphinxbase and pocketsphinx on Debian Jessie as detailed in [this tutorial](http://lowyeeling.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/installing-sphinxbase-and-pocketsphinx/) but running `make check` during the installation of sphinxbase is failing; I think this is leading to my inability to install pocketsphinx later.  When I check the appropriate log, it reveals the source of the error:

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(697): Parsing command line:
/home/username/projects/sphinx/sphinxbase/test/unit/test_fe/.libs/lt-test_fe 

Current configuration:
[NAME]      [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-alpha      0.97        9.700000e-01
-dither     no      no
-doublebw   no      no
-frate      100     100
-input_endian   little      little
-lifter     0       0
-logspec    no      no
-lowerf     133.33334   1.333333e+02
-ncep       13      13
-nfft       512     512
-nfilt      40      40
-remove_dc  no      no
-remove_noise   yes     yes
-remove_silence yes     yes
-round_filters  yes     yes
-samprate   16000       1.600000e+04
-seed       -1      -1
-smoothspec no      no
-transform  legacy      legacy
-unit_area  yes     yes
-upperf     6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-vad_postspeech 50      50
-vad_prespeech  10      10
-vad_threshold  2.0     2.000000e+00
-verbose    no      no
-warp_params            
-warp_type  inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen       0.025625    2.562500e-02

FAIL: fabs((cepbuf1[3][i]) - (cepbuf2[0][i])) < EPSILON
frame_size 410 frame_shift 160
inptr 1024 nsamp 0 nfr 0
inptr 1024 nsamp 0 nfr 0
inptr 1024 nsamp 0 nfr 0
inptr 1024 nsamp 0 nfr 0
nfr 0
nfr 0
nfr 0
3: 0.00,4.95
```

I poked around cmd_ln.c a little, and it looks like the offending line is in a win32-related #ifndef, which makes it possibly irrelevant in this situation?  I'm not sure.

Has anyone else had this problem or can anyone else shed some light on the subject for me?

Comment: to start with, the base directory (which you were instructed to start at via a cd /usr/src was not done

Comment: make check is expected to fail for now, you can proceed without that.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Alright.  Perhaps the error is in Pocketsphinx then; it's throwing a "too few arguments" error when compiling.

Comment: Please provide more information about error (the log). Most likely you didn't install sphinxbase properly or you have different sphinxbase installations (one from repository probably). Overall, SO is for software development, if you have troubles to install software, it's better to use cmusphinx forums on sourceforge.

Comment: Good point, will do.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that if I use the latest codebase hosted on CMU's git repo and use the instructions provided by them for installation, everything goes perfectly smoothly.

Go figure.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score -1):

Skip *make check* and run *make install*